# How do I set a tag with AWS boto3 "request_spot_fleet", unique to that spot fleet, when using a launch template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, boto

I'm using AWS boto3 "*request_spot_fleet*" to launch spot fleets. I have a launch template that contains the information for the spot fleet and its instances.

The launch template contains tags which are set for all spot fleets that are requested (created) with that template. I also want to add  tags unique to each spot fleet, when I create a particular spot fleet request.

I've tried the following as the SpotFleetRequestConfig:

```
SpotFleetRequestConfig= {
    'IamFleetRole': FLEET_ROLE,
    'TagSpecifications': [
        {
            'ResourceType': 'spot-fleet-request',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'UNIQUE_TO_THIS_SPLOT_FLEET',
                    'Value': UNIQUE_TO_THIS_SPLOT_FLEET
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    'LaunchTemplateConfigs': [
        {
            'LaunchTemplateSpecification': {
                'LaunchTemplateId': LaunchTemplateId,
                'Version': Version,
            },
            'Overrides': [
                {
                    'InstanceType': InstanceTypeFormat,
                    'SubnetId': LAUNCH_SUBNETS,
                },
            ],
            
        },
    ],
    'SpotPrice': MAX_SPOT_PRICE,
    'TargetCapacity': int(TargetCapacity),
}
```

This creates the spot fleet but does not seem to add the tag.

Is it possible to add tags when creating a spot fleet with a launch template?

Comment: Add tags to what? The actual instances in your fleets?

Comment: Yes the instances of a specific Spot Fleet Request. The launch template (and its tags) can be applied to numerous Spot Fleets. 

At spot fleet creation however, I'd like to add a unique tag to all instances that launch from that spot fleet request being created (along with the ones that are set for all fleets in the launch template)

Comment: No responses. It seems it is not possible to set spot fleet tags at the time the spot fleet request is made, if you are using a launch template.

Only tags within the launch template are possible.